# how do i search for a file and when found set the file path to a variable in a batch script

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I am trying to create a batch file that will run and open a Powershell script to then run.

this is what i have so far

```
@echo off
for /r C:\folder %%a in (*) do if "%%~nxa"=="2WNRN4VMS2.txt" set p=%%~dpnxa
if defined p (
echo %p%
) else (
echo File not found
Pause
)
Powershell.exe -Command "& '%p%'"
exit
```

Comment: You have not asked a question.  What do you want to know?

Comment: If you want the powershell command to run when the variable is defined then you need to move the powershell command into the TRUE portion of your IF block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is very simple using command **DIR** for searching for the file recursively in folder `C:\folder` and all its subfolders and command **FOR** for assigning the drive and path of found file to an environment variable:

```
@echo off
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir /A-D /B /S "C:\folder\2WNRN4VMS2.txt" 2^>nul') do set "FilePath=%%~dpI" & goto FoundFile
echo File not found
pause
goto :EOF

:FoundFile
Powershell.exe -Command "& '%FilePath%'"
```

Please note that the string assigned to environment variable `FilePath` ends with a backslash. Use in `PowerShell` command line `%FilePath:~0,-1%` if the path of the file should be passed without a backslash at end.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `pause /?`
- `set /?`